# Insert empty string to Oracle database from SQL Server result strange characters

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have two databases Oracle (10.2.0.4) and SQL Server (2008 R2).

When I insert data through linked server:

```
EXECUTE( 'begin INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID,data1,NIP) VALUES(?,sysdate,?);  end;',           
          '', 
          ''
         ) AT LS_ORACLE;
```

result in `TEST_TABLE` as:

```
id | data1  | NIP
-----------------
ǧ  |16/07/21|
```

Empty string is convert to "ǧ".

How to eliminate this strange behavior?

For information:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_TABLE" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "DATA1" DATE, 
    "NIP" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use my workaround. 
When you'll use variables this problem is solved

```
declare @id nvarchar(50) = ''
,@nip nvarchar(50) = ''
EXECUTE( 'begin INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE(ID,data1,NIP) VALUES(?,sysdate,?);  end;',           
      @id, 
      @nip
     ) AT LS_ORACLE
```